# Prevent user from overwriting query string parameter with Nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, query-string

I have the following Nginx rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /post.php?slug=$1 last;
```

Nginx will now apply rewrites like the following:

```
/a -> /post.php?slug=a
/a?slug=b -> /post.php?slug=a&slug=b
```

The second example is problematic. How can I prevent visitors from adding query string parameters that are already added by rewrite rules? Other query string parameters may still be supplied. Examples of desired behavior:

```
/a -> /post.php?slug=a
/a?slug=b -> /post.php?slug=a
/a?foo=b -> /post.php?slug=a&foo=b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `slug` query argument:

```
location ~ ^/(?<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)$ {
    if ($args ~ (.*)(^|&)slug=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
        set $args $1$3$4;
    }
    rewrite ^ /post.php?slug=$slug last;
}
```

This complex regex would remove `slug` query argument from query arguments string regardless of whether it is at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of that string.